# Content on a page defined by text in a field, publications by year

Tags: channel-entries, templates, fieldtype, fields, channel-fields

I know someone out there has done this before. 
I need to build a publications page that will show it's list of publications by a given year which has been filled in a channel field. I've googled I looked at the EE docs and I am not quite sure how to build this.

I have a channel field that will be filled with a 4 number year my content managers.
Here is my basics. It of course lists all years in descending order but i need to make a separate page for "2015, 2014, 2013, etc."

Thanks for looking.

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="publications" 
   orderby="pub_year"
   sort="desc"
   paginate="both"
   limit="8"
   }

          <h3 style="font-size: 1em; margin-bottom:3px;">{pub_year}</h3>

          <p><a href="{pub_year}">{title}.</a></p> 
         <!-- Etc. -->

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use the search parameter in conjunction with the url so you could access each year with something like

http://yoursite.com/template_group/year/2015

Then in your code you could do:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="publications" 
   orderby="pub_year"
   search:pub_year="={last_segment}"
   sort="desc"
   paginate="both"
   limit="8"
   }

          <h3 style="font-size: 1em; margin-bottom:3px;">{pub_year}</h3>

          <p><a href="{pub_year}">{title}.</a></p> 
         <!-- Etc. -->

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I got no returns it doesn't seem to be seeing the last segment. I tried {if last_segment == '2014'}Last segment is 2014 {/if}  to verify what was seen  and it wouldn't return anything with search:pub_year="={last_segment}" but would on the regular last segment {if last_segment == 'year'} Last segment is year {/if}

Comment: I've stripped down to essentially what you have there no extraneous mark up, no js no css. it don't like the search:pub_year="={last_segment}" I've googled and looked at the docs seems like it should work. but no go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Johnathan, this put me on the right path. The final piece missing is (dynamic="no"). It appears it seems to think these are "id"s and is not returning the correct results. So the full answer is. Again Thanks!!

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="publications" 
   orderby="pub_year"
   search:pub_year="={last_segment}"
   dynamic="no"
   sort="desc"
   limit="8"
   }

        <h3 style="font-size: 1em; margin-bottom:3px;">{pub_year}</h3>

        <p><a href="{pub_year}">{title}.</a></p> 
         <!-- Etc. -->

{/exp:channel:entries}
```